# Different titles for a table rate shipping module

Tags: shipping, table-rates

Is there a pretty way to override table rates shipping method title for order confirmation email and order details page (customer account) based on shipping address country?

So far I see cloning an entire shipping method wich allowed countries restriction and using [WebShopApps MatrixRate](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension-certified-bug-free.html) extension as alternatives but I'm not happy with those options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the same without a rewrite using an observer:

```
<sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
    <observers>
        <your_module>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>your_module/observer</class>
            <method>salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore</method>
        </your_module>
    </observers>
</sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
```

Then, in the observer:

```
public function salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote */
    $quote = $observer->getQuote();

    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
    $store->setConfig('carriers/tablerate/name', 'Name By Country');
    $store->setConfig('carriers/tablerate/title', 'Method Title By Country');
}
```

Setting the config values dynamically without saving them is a cheap trick but it works pretty well.
The benefit of using an observer over a class rewrite is that it's less conflict prone.

Comment: :) nice trick. We can change anything related to carrier by the way. +1

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found a sort of solution by myself.

It would be making a custom module, overriding `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` and adding a new method `getShippingDescription()` there. This will make magic `getShippingDescription()` not so magic and the custom logic can be placed there based on `$this->getCountry()` or any other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Also try this one:
In config.xml rewrite Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method class:

```
<global>
  <models>
    <shipping>
      <rewrite>
        <rate_result_method>{{Some}}_{{Module}}_Model_Rate_Result_Method</rate_result_method>
      </rewrite>
    </shipping>
  </models>
</global>
```

Create Method.php file in local/{{Some}}/{{Module}}/Model/Rate/Result and its methods will be:

```
class {{Some}}_{{Module}}_Model_Rate_Result_Method extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method
{
    public function getMethodTitle(){
         //your logic here
    }
    public function getMethodDescription(){
         //your logic here
    }
}
```